# Not able to open the Jmx file in Jmeter

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jmx

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOM1l.png)Please click here to check the error

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1VHb.png)Please click here to check the error
While open the .jmx file in Jmeter we are facing the above issue in Jmeter. Any can able to find the solution for this error?

we are try to open the jmx in 2.12,2.13,3.0 and 3.1 version but we are facing the above issue. **But same jmx we can able to open in different system**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have some missing plugins (i.e libraries).
So please double check that you have the same libraries on the different systems
you can check the libraries by going on to the folder 
apache-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\lib

Replace the missing libraries by copy paste then restart jmeter

Answer (score 3):

Jmeter version 5.4.1 was not loading existing jmx file, it started working after I changed the theme from Dracula to windows.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone facing a error in opening the jmx file

Try this

Open jmeter
Select option
Select look and feel
And select the windows option

Wait till jmeter gets restart

And try to open the jmx file again

Answer (score 1):

It is due to missing plugin in the JMeter version. The JMX file contains references to a plugin called [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/).

So, download it and keep in `/lib/ext` folder and restart JMeter. Import the script, it will work. If error occurs, it might depends on some other plugins, so identify them and add it to JMeter as mentioned above.

Note: You can use [Plugin Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) for easy management of plugins.

Answer (score 1):

If on mac:

1. Options -> Look and Feel
2. Select Nimbus
3. Click 'Yes' to restart
   Try saving or opening a file
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQxd3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop your file and it will work